# Read table cell values(<td>) using table row(<tr>) id with Javascript only

Tags: javascript, html-table, row, cell

I have a table as follows:

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tr id='id1'>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td >Cell B</td>
    <td >Cell C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='id2'>
    <td >Cell D</td>
    <td>Cell E</td>
    <td>Cell F</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I know the row id `id1` I want read all the cells I mean `<td>` of that particular  using table id and row id. That means I need to read values `Cell A, Cell B, Cell C`

Note: use Javascript only

Comment: Are you fine with jQuery?

Comment: @DeepakBiswal no buddy I need it with javascript only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the demo [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssv9zfwe/5/).

**HTML**

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tr id='id1'>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td >Cell B</td>
    <td >Cell C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='id2'>
    <td >Cell D</td>
    <td>Cell E</td>
    <td>Cell F</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var tr = document.getElementById('id1');
var td = tr.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i=0;i<td.length;i++) {
    console.log(td[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Hope this is what you need!